# When update a JavaScript object, what value to provide to keep the value to be the same

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, null, key-value

This is my program:

```
let existingData = {
    name: 'David',
    age: 32,
    isSingle: true,
    country: 'United States'
};

let input = {
    name: 'Mike',
    age: null, // The question is how to keep age value to be 32
    isSingle: false,
    country: 'France'
};

existingData['name'] = input['name'];
existingData['age'] = input['age'];
existingData['isSingle'] = input['isSingle'];
existingData['country'] = input['country'];

console.log(existingData);
```

When I run it, this is what I see:

```
{
    name: 'Mike',
    age: null,
    isSingle: false,
    country: 'France'
}
```

This is what I expect:

```
{
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 32,
    isSingle: false,
    country: 'France'
}
```

So my question is what value should I provide to input age in order to keep the value 32.
I tried null but it does not work.

Is there any possible way to solve this ?

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot, for example, modify the line `existingData['name'] = input['name'];`? You can only modify the `existingData['age'] = input['age'];` line, and no other parts of the program? That's a very strange restriction

Comment: @CertainPerformance There are no any restrictions like that, I just edited my post. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Simple short circuit approach `existingData['age'] = input['age'] || existingData['age'];`

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Fails if the input is 0, which I'd expect to be a valid value for an "age" field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the general case, you can filter out the null values with `.filter` and `Object.entries`, then use `Object.assign`:

```js
let existingData = {
    name: 'David',
    age: 32,
    isSingle: true,
    country: 'United States'
};

let input = {
    name: 'Mike',
    age: null, // The question is how to keep age value to be 32
    isSingle: false,
    country: 'France'
};

Object.assign(
  existingData,
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(input).filter(([, val]) => val !== null)
  )
);
console.log(existingData);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conditional operator like the ternary operator to check if the value in `input` is null. If it is `null` it will assign the value from `existingData` and if not null, it will assign the `input` object value.

```js
let existingData = {
    name: 'David',
    age: 32,
    isSingle: true,
    country: 'United States'
};

let input = {
    name: 'Mike',
    age: null, // The question is how to keep age value to be 32
    isSingle: false,
    country: 'France'
};

existingData['name'] = input['name'];
existingData['age'] = input['age'] === null ? existingData['age'] : input['age'];
existingData['isSingle'] = input['isSingle'];
existingData['country'] = input['country'];

console.log(existingData);
```